# Appending some stings inside a list in R

Tags: r, list

Data from web scraping was saved to a list. Some elements however weren't available on every page, resulting in the list having character vectors of different length (4 if all data was present, 3 if it wasn't).

Since I need to retain the specific structure of the list, I decided to append the same value to all of the records with the missing data.

Doing so manually works, however when trying to write a loop, it ends up replacing the missing values with the appended value, resulting in character vectors of length 1.

Some example data:

```
things <- list(c("red", "small", "expensive", "car"),
               c("big", "expensive", "bike"),
               c("green", "big", "cheap", "bike"),
               c("small", "expensive", "car"))
```

Let's say that we know that every thing with the missing first record (color) was blue. Manually appending it works as expected, returning ("blue" "big" "expensive" "bike") for the 2nd record for example.

```
c("blue", things[[2]])
```

However trying to translate it into a loop to go through all of the data, based on an ifelse statement of the character length, it replaces the whole vector with "blue" instead of appending it.

```
all_things <- list()

for(i in seq_along(things)) {
  all_things[i] <- ifelse(length(things[[i]]) == 3, c("blue", things[[i]]), things[i])
}
```

Running the loop returns:

> [[1]]
> [1] "red"       "small"     "expensive" "car"

> [[2]]
> [1] "blue"

> [[3]]
> [1] "green" "big"   "cheap" "bike"

> [[4]]
> [1] "blue"

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great answers! In the end, I went with the answer from @Sotos, but all of the proposed solutions work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to check your condition, i.e.

```
lapply(things, \(i) if(length(i) == 3) {c('blue', i)}else{i})

[[1]]
[1] "red"       "small"     "expensive" "car"      

[[2]]
[1] "blue"      "big"       "expensive" "bike"     

[[3]]
[1] "green" "big"   "cheap" "bike" 

[[4]]
[1] "blue"      "small"     "expensive" "car"
```

Answer (score 3):

I’d do this in two steps:

1. prepend the “missing” value to *all* list items
2. take just the last 4 values from each list item

This two-step process means we don’t need to use `ifelse`, and we do not need a loop:

```
lapply(things, append, "blue", after = 0L) |> lapply(tail, 4L)
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "red"       "small"     "expensive" "car"

[[2]]
[1] "blue"      "big"       "expensive" "bike"

[[3]]
[1] "green" "big"   "cheap" "bike"

[[4]]
[1] "blue"      "small"     "expensive" "car"
```

This is one of the very rare cases where `append` instead of  `c` is appropriate (even though we *pre*pend; showing once again that `append` is misnamed).

Comment: I'm curious why you prefer `append()` over `c()` in this case?

Comment: Why not just 1 lapply ? `lapply(things, \(i)tail(append(i, "blue", after = 0L),4L))`

Comment: @Sotos Because then I need to use a lambda.

Comment: @dufei Because then the order is wrong. I need to use `append` with the `after = 0L` argument to *pre*pend the value. Of course alternatively I could use an anonymous function but I often avoid them if I can get away with it (such as here), by basically “ungrouping” a nested operation into multiple applications (kind of like the function application equivalent of factorisation).

Comment: so you prefer looping twice rather than once with lambda function? Okay. Also note that `append` is just `c` under the hood. Amazing answer though

Comment: @onyambu The number of loops isn't really all that relevant here. What matters more is readability, and I generally try to avoid lambdas if I can decompose the call such that I am directly calling the individual functions. That said, it really depends on the concrete case which I find more readable, and in this particular case I am pretty undecided: I also like the other posted answers, and I'm not even sure I would end up using the code I posted (I actually prefer your answer). — Regarding `append`: I know it uses `c` internally but how is this relevant?

Answer (score 3):

You can try `lengths` + `Map` if you work with base R

```
> things[lengths(things) == 3] <- Map(c, "blue", things[lengths(things) == 3])

> things
[[1]]
[1] "red"       "small"     "expensive" "car"

[[2]]
[1] "blue"      "big"       "expensive" "bike"

[[3]]
[1] "green" "big"   "cheap" "bike"

[[4]]
[1] "blue"      "small"     "expensive" "car"
```

Answer (score 3):

you could also use

```
purrr::map_at(things, lengths(things) == 3, ~c('blue', .x))

[[1]]
[1] "red"       "small"     "expensive" "car"      

[[2]]
[1] "blue"      "big"       "expensive" "bike"     

[[3]]
[1] "green" "big"   "cheap" "bike" 

[[4]]
[1] "blue"      "small"     "expensive" "car"
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

things <- list(c("red", "small", "expensive", "car"),
               c("big", "expensive", "bike"),
               c("green", "big", "cheap", "bike"),
               c("small", "expensive", "car"))

map(
  things,
  ~if (length(.x) == 3L) c("blue", .x) else .x
)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "red"       "small"     "expensive" "car"      
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "blue"      "big"       "expensive" "bike"     
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "green" "big"   "cheap" "bike" 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "blue"      "small"     "expensive" "car"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over with lapply and add "blue" in front of each vector of length 3

```r
things[lengths(things) == 3] <- lapply(things[lengths(things) == 3], \(x) c("blue", x))
things
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "red"       "small"     "expensive" "car"      
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "blue"      "big"       "expensive" "bike"     
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "green" "big"   "cheap" "bike" 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "blue"      "small"     "expensive" "car"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your code like this:

```
all_things <- list()

for(i in seq_along(things)) {
  all_things[[i]] <- if(length(things[[i]]) == 3) c("blue", things[[i]]) else things[[i]]
}
```

Here we use `[[` instead of `[` and `if () {} else {}` instead of `ifelse`. You should study the documentation of `ifelse`.